# Which gum/gums to use to get a gummy texture when using Agar agar powder

Tags: food-science, vegan, ingredients

Trying to do a school project that needs me to make gummies from scratch in an innovative way. I decided to go with Agar agar for a vegan based gummy. Unfortunately, once I make the gummies the agar agar sets but I don’t get the gummy/chewy texture that is required. What should I use in conjunction with the agar agar to get this texture without having to compromise the vegan factor?

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the texture by adding stuff to it. It is done the other way around - you decide what texture you want to end up with, and choose the thickener that gives you the proper texture.

Agar agar gives you a brittle texture. If you want a gummylike texture the way you know it from gelatine-based candy, you have to use gelatine.

Vegan gelatine exists too, it's the result of professional food engineers spending a lot of research time on mimicking the final texture. It should give you the desired texture while keeping the product vegan. You have to purchase it as a separate product, it's not just a different name for a more conventional thickener.